# exports issue when compile TS => JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying TypeScript especially to work with classes but I encounter an issue after my TS file is compiled in JS.

Here is the TS code for my class (PartenaireTSModel.ts):

```
export namespace Partenaires {
    export class Partenaire {
        private _IdPartenaire : number;
        private _DateCreation : Date;   

        public get IdPartenaire(){ return this._IdPartenaire; }
        public set IdPartenaire(idPartenaire: number){ this._IdPartenaire = idPartenaire; }

        public get DateCreation(){ return this._DateCreation; }
        public set DateCreation(dateCreation: Date){ this._DateCreation = dateCreation; }
    }
}
```

My TS code (Partenaires.ts):

```
import { Partenaires } from "./Models/PartenaireTSModel"

let partenaire = new Partenaires.Partenaire();
partenaire.IdPartenaire = 12;
```

After compiling the result in JS (Partenaires.js):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var PartenaireTSModel_1 = require("./Models/PartenaireTSModel");
var partenaire = new PartenaireTSModel_1.Partenaires.Partenaire();
partenaire.IdPartenaire = 12;
```

I have this error when I launch my app : **Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined.** (on line 2 of Partenaires.js)

Also tried :

```
import p = require("./Models/PartenaireTSModel");
let partenaire = new p.Partenaires.Partenaire();
```

instead of this :

```
import { Partenaires } from "./Models/PartenaireTSModel"
let partenaire = new Partenaires.Partenaire();
```

But I get the same error.

Here is my tsconfig.js :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "TSScripts/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Thank you,

Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"module": "es6",` in the `compilerOptions` object of tsconfig.json file. (So, the generated modules code runs natively in the browsers)